# How to get XML response in readable format in flight API

Tags: php, api, curl, response

I am using travelport flight API. When I send request by curl getting response in non readable format. How to get flight API response in readable?

**RESPONSE**

```
 H4sIAAAAAAAAAJ1UTUwTQRR+bSk/ghLEEINRNBrh4m5pBVrxooAEskWkaEIrh2F3ugxud5bZaVmMMdGL8eDFi8HEBGMkmnjgaGLiVQ8eiPFgYjwYzt4lMcGZpQVWoo32sN1588333vveN/vqO0RdBq1zqISUIieWcoExtKgRl3t3Ph5deoeeRCA0AjUuuYk9BwBCCzXyKQ6d0WlBMePuAuH6rGIaroI
```

Comment: Have you tried any **decoding**?

Comment: Try following one of their examples, it appears they return xml, but could return other formats. https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Getting_Started/Sending_Requests/Sample_Request_and_Response.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520Started%7CSending%2520Requests%7C_____3

Comment: @Naruto doesn't look like it decodes to anything https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: hello sir, i am not getting proper answer. can i send code.

Comment: @PhilCooper sir i get output properly but not xml format,my work require this output to be in xml problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited grammar - i to I, first letter of sentences and remove unnecessary last sentence `Please help me`.